# Why are cosh(x) and sinh(x) defined with denominator of 2?

Tags: analysis, hyperbolic-functions

Looking at graphs of $2sinh(x)$ and $e^x$ they match perfectly in the right half of $xy$ plane. Wouldn't it make more sense to define $sinh(x)$ as $sinh(x)=e^x-e^{-x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That might be useful if that definition was the only thing $\sinh$ was good for. However, there are *many* properties that necessitate the $\frac12$. Some algebraic properties are
$$
e^x = \sinh x + \cosh x\\
\cosh^2 x - \sinh^2x = 1\\
$$
In addition, there are the algebraic-geometric properties, connecting $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ to the hyperbola $x^2-y^2 = 1$ as tightly as $\sin$ and $\cos$ are connected to the circle $x^2+y^2 = 1$. All of these are nice enough that we can stand to live with a $\frac12$ factor without too many issues.

Comment: also $\cosh{0}=\cos{0}$ and $\sinh{0}=\sin{0}$, $\cos{x}=\cosh{ix}$ and $i\sin{x}=\sinh{ix}$

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Which is to say, the unit circle and the unit hyperbola are really just two different cross sections of the same object.

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja:  wouldn't $\sinh0=\sin0$ still hold without the $\frac12$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner ahh that's true but for cos it needs the denominator

Answer (score 2):

For each function $f$, we can define an even and odd part:
$$f_\text{e}(x)=\frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2} \\
f_\text{o}(x)=\frac{f(x)-f(-x)}{2} $$
so that $f(x)=f_\text{e}(x)+f_\text{o}(x)$. If we apply this to $x\mapsto e^x$, we get
$$e^x=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}+\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2} $$
so $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ are, respectively, the even and odd parts of $e^x$.